# How can I have decorator.other?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

This is the structure I'm trying to accomplish with my code. I want to use registry.filter and registry.action to load in filters and actions for an application I'm building. I recognize that I could just split them up into two different decorators.

```
def registry():
    def filter(*expected_args):
        def decorator(func):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            return wrapper
        return decorator

    def filter(*expected_args):
        def decorator(func):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            return wrapper
        return decorator


@registry.filter({

})
def my_filter():
    print "Hello World!"

@registry.action({

})
def my_action():
    print "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_filter()
    my_action()
```

Whenever I run my code I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chris/Documents/Content-Management/registry.py", line 19, in <module>
    @registry.filter({
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

Comment: Functions don't store things defined in their bodies as attributes. You'll need  a class or a separate module to get behavior like that. A module seems more appropriate here.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for your help. I've got it working now.